# How to add an image to a table with Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

So I have the following code:

```
items = [ ["Photo","Name", "Qty", "Unit Price", "Amount"] ]
items += @quotation.quotation_items.map do |oitem|
[
   pdf.image(oitem.item.photo),
   oitem.item.title,
   oitem.quantity.to_s,
   number_to_currency(oitem.item.price,:unit => 'HK$ '),
   number_to_currency(oitem.full_price,:unit => 'HK$ ')
]
```

This generates the error:

```
Content type not recognized: #<Prawn::Images::JPG:0x00000101703b98 @bits=8, @height=300, @width=300, @channels=3, @scaled_width=300, @scaled_height=300>
```

Extracted source (around line #54):

```
51: 
52: end
53: 
54: pdf.table items, :header => true,
55:                  :column_widths => [300,200,100,150,150],
56:                  :row_colors => ["FFFFFF","DDDDDD"]
57:
```

Comment: From what I can tell an image object is not acceptable in a table cell [prawn suitable cell types](http://rdoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/master/Prawn/Table/Cell/Subtable). You will prob have to do a for each loop of bounding_boxes instead of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a Mock table with Images that helped me a lot. Thanks to jfeust for sharing it wih us.  - https://gist.github.com/973267